Unable to deploy all-in-one standalone openstack 16.1 on Redhat Linux 8, facing issues with puppet
I have done the installation and configuration as mentioned in the documentation. Now to deploy OpenStack on the linux machine I run the following command
[stack@all-in-one]$ sudo openstack tripleo deploy \
--templates \
--local-ip=$IP/$NETMASK \
-e /usr/share/openstack-tripleo-heat-templates/environments/standalone/standalonetripleo.yaml \
-r /usr/share/openstack-tripleo-heat-templates/roles/Standalone.yaml \
-e $HOME/containers-prepare-parameters.yaml \
-e $HOME/standalone_parameters.yaml \
--output-dir $HOME \
--standalone \
--output-only

but while this command is running I face the following error:
TASK [Wait for puppet host configuration to finish] ***************************************************************************************************************************************
Thursday 08 August 2024  05:12:00 +0000 (0:00:00.636)       0:09:19.791 *******
WAITING FOR COMPLETION: Wait for puppet host configuration to finish (360 retries left).
WAITING FOR COMPLETION: Wait for puppet host configuration to finish (359 retries left).
WAITING FOR COMPLETION: Wait for puppet host configuration to finish (358 retries left).
WAITING FOR COMPLETION: Wait for puppet host configuration to finish (357 retries left).
WAITING FOR COMPLETION: Wait for puppet host configuration to finish (356 retries left).
WAITING FOR COMPLETION: Wait for puppet host configuration to finish (355 retries left).
fatal: [all-in-one]: FAILED! => {"ansible_job_id": "221397696149.19566", "attempts": 7, "changed": true, "cmd": "set -o pipefail; puppet apply  --modulepath=/etc/puppet/modules:/opt/stack/puppet-modules:/usr/share/openstack-puppet/modules --detailed-exitcodes --summarize --color=false   /var/lib/tripleo-config/puppet_step_config.pp 2>&1 | logger -s -t puppet-user", "delta": "0:00:56.349311", "end": "2024-08-08 05:12:57.478885", "failed_when_result": true, "finished": 1, "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 6, "start": "2024-08-08 05:12:01.129574", "stderr": "<13>Aug  8 05:12:01 puppet-user: Warning: The function 'hiera' is deprecated in favor of using 'lookup'. See https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/deprecated_language.html\\n   (file & line not available)\n<13>Aug  8 05:12:01 puppet-user: Warning: /etc/puppet/hiera.yaml: Use of 'hiera.yaml' version 3 is deprecated. It should be converted to version 5\n<13>Aug  8 05:12:01 puppet-user:    (file: /etc/puppet/hiera.yaml)\n<13>Aug  8 05:12:01 puppet-user: Warning: Undefined variable '::deploy_config_name'; \\n   (file & line not available)\n<13>Aug  8 05:12:01 puppet-user: Warning: ModuleLoader: module 'tripleo' has unresolved dependencies - it will only see those that are resolved. Use 'puppet module list --tree' to see information about modules\\n   (file & line not available)\n<13>Aug  8 05:12:01 puppet-user: Warning: Unknown variable: '::deployment_type'. (file: /etc/puppet/modules/tripleo/manifests/profile/base/database/mysql/client.pp, line: 89, column: 8)\n
<13>Aug  8 05:12:01 puppet-user: Warning: ModuleLoader: module 'aodh' has unresolved dependencies - it will only see those that are resolved. Use 'puppet module list --tree' to see information about modules\\n   (file & line not available)\n<13>Aug  8 05:12:01 puppet-user: Warning: ModuleLoader: module 'openstacklib' has unresolved dependencies - it will only see those that are resolved. Use 'puppet module list --tree' to see information about modules\\n   (file & line not available)\n<13>Aug  8 05:12:01 puppet-user: Warning: ModuleLoader: module 'barbican' has unresolved dependencies - it will only see those that are resolved. Use 'puppet module list --tree' to see information about modules\\n


(file & line not available)\n<13>Aug  8 05:12:01 puppet-user: Warning: ModuleLoader: module 'cinder' has unresolved dependencies - it will only see those that are resolved. Use 'puppet module list --tree' to see information about modules\\n   (file & line not available)\n<13>Aug  8 05:12:01 puppet-user: Warning: ModuleLoader: module 'designate' has unresolved dependencies - it will only see those that are resolved. Use 'puppet module list --tree' to see information about modules\\n   (file & line not available)\n<13>Aug  8 05:12:01 puppet-user: Warning: ModuleLoader: module 'glance' has unresolved dependencies - it will only see those that are resolved. Use 'puppet module list --tree' to see information about modules\\n   (file & line not available)\n<13>Aug  8 05:12:01 puppet-user: Warning: ModuleLoader: module 'gnocchi' has unresolved dependencies - it will only see those that are resolved. Use 'puppet module list --tree' to see information about modules\\n   (file & line not available)\n<13>Aug  8 05:12:01 puppet-user: Warning: ModuleLoader: module 'heat' has unresolved dependencies - it will only see those that are resolved. Use 'puppet module list --tree' to see information about modules\\n   (file & line not available)\n<13>Aug  8 05:12:01 puppet-user: Warning: ModuleLoader: module 'ironic' has unresolved dependencies - it will only see those that are resolved. Use 'puppet module list --tree' to see information about modules\\n   (file & line not available)\n<13>Aug  8 05:12:01 puppet-user: Warning: ModuleLoader: module 'keystone' has unresolved dependencies - it will only see those that are resolved. Use 'puppet module list --tree' to see information about modules\\n   (file & line not available)\n<13>Aug  8 05:12:01 puppet-user: Warning: ModuleLoader: module 'manila' has unresolved dependencies - it will only see those that are resolved. Use 'puppet module list --tree' to see information about modules\\n   (file & line not available)\n<13>Aug  8 05:12:01 puppet-user: Warning: ModuleLoader: module 'mistral' has unresolved dependencies - it will only see those that are resolved. Use 'puppet module list --tree' to see information about modules\\n   (file & line not available)\n<13>Aug  8 05:12:01 puppet-user:

....

NO MORE HOSTS LEFT ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
all-in-one                 : ok=220  changed=72   unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=77   rescued=0    ignored=0
undercloud                 : ok=23   changed=10   unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=3    rescued=0    ignored=0

Thursday 08 August 2024  05:13:03 +0000 (0:01:02.858)       0:10:22.650 *******
===============================================================================
Pre-fetch all the containers ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 209.77s
Wait for puppet host configuration to finish -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 62.86s
tripleo-container-tag : Pull registry.redhat.io/rhosp-rhel8/openstack-cinder-volume:16.1 image ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 13.98s
Install tuned --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 12.58s
tripleo-hieradata : Render hieradata from template -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 12.55s
tripleo-bootstrap : Deploy required packages to bootstrap TripleO ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 10.84s
tripleo-container-tag : Pull registry.redhat.io/rhosp-rhel8/openstack-mariadb:16.1 image ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 10.26s
tripleo-hieradata : Render hieradata from template -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 10.24s
ensure LVM rpm dependencies are installed ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 10.19s
Ensure rsyslog is installed ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 10.02s
tripleo-podman : ensure podman and deps are installed ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 9.96s
Install chronyd package ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 9.91s
tripleo-kernel : Remove dracut-config-generic -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 9.87s
tripleo-image-serve : ensure apache is installed ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 9.73s
tripleo-bootstrap : Deploy network-scripts required for deprecated network service ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 9.49s
install tmpwatch on the host ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 9.42s
tripleo-container-tag : Pull registry.redhat.io/rhosp-rhel8/openstack-rabbitmq:16.1 image ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 8.59s
tripleo-kernel : Set extra sysctl options ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 7.51s
tripleo-podman : Perform container registry login(s) with podman ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 6.74s
tripleo-network-config : Run NetworkConfig script ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 4.58s
Exception: Deployment failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tripleoclient/v1/tripleo_deploy.py", line 1328, in _standalone_deploy
    raise exceptions.DeploymentError('Deployment failed')
tripleoclient.exceptions.DeploymentError: Deployment failed
None
Not cleaning working directory /root/tripleo-heat-installer-templates
Not cleaning ansible directory /root/standalone-ansible-opf_83g8
Install artifact is located at /root/standalone-install-20240808051303.tar.bzip2

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Deployment Failed!

ERROR: Heat log files: /var/log/heat-launcher/undercloud_deploy-1300uydd

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

now this is just a small part of the error as deployment displays a long log with similar error messages. Furthermore, the issue I face is when this error occurs is that my ssh file is changed somehow and the password_authentication parameter inside the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file is changed from yes to no, making me unable to access my VM using softwares like Xschell or Putty.
This error started happening after I reinstalled the Puppet, Is there any issue with puppet dependencies?
Does anybody have any clue how to solve this and potentially deploying the openstack on the VM?
Thanks in advance!

You probably should use a supported deployment method, the last supported tripleo version was Wallaby. Something like devstack or kolla-ansible should be worth a try.
